# Webpack resolve.root and TypeScript loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, webpack, ts-loader

Our project is using the webpack `resolve.root` option to import modules with absolute paths. (avoiding something like `../../../module`)
In its current state the project is using *babel-loader* which works perfectly fine.
My task is to migrate the app to Angular 2.
Therefor I am currently in the process of transitioning to TypeScript.
Somehow it seems like the *ts-loader* does not work in combination with the `resolve.root` option of the webpack config.

Example of the **webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
    root: [
        path.resolve('./node_modules'),
        path.resolve('./app'),
        path.resolve('./app/lib'),
    ]
},
```

Example of a module import
`import AbstractListState from 'states/abstract_list_state';`

The `states` directory is inside the `app/lib` directory.

Error when executing `webpack`

```
ERROR in ./app/mainViews/panel/panel.controller.ts
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'states/abstract_list_state' in C:\Users\...\Project\app\mainViews\panel
 @ ./app/mainViews/panel/panel.controller.ts 4:28-65
```

Comment: See: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039. A way to do this with `tsconfig.json` file will be implemented in TypeScript 2. Apparently, you can already test it today with `typescript@next`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre version 2.0 TypeScript will try to load modules with an absolute path from the `node_modules` directory. This is because TypeScript's module resultion is per default set to "node". Which means it works like node's require method. So, even if you're using webpack to build your app, TypeScript (and its compiler) will still want to load the files.

In order to let webpack import your modules with absolute path you have to go back and use the `require` method. This way TypeScript will let webpack import stuff. But of course you will not get any type-inference, autocomplete, ...

Or, you update to the TypeScript 2.0 beta and give this a try: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#module-resolution-enhancements-baseurl-path-mapping-rootdirs-and-tracing